# running app in ios 10 using xcode 7.3.1

Tags: xcode, swift2, ios10, xcode7.3

Hi i have developed a app using Xcode 7.3.1 and swift 2.2 my app will execute upto the deployed target 9.3 but i want to execute my app in latest versions also that is iOS10. I don't want to update my Xcode to latest Xcode version.so is there any possible to support my app to latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow with this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928402/4935811)

1. Download this imageFile iOS 10.2 here:
2. Copy this iOS 10.2 image file to: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
3. Restart Xcode.

Comment: yes i have done every thing what you said..but in my Xcode deployment target still shows upto 9.3 only

Comment: yes it not show in deployment target but you can run it.

Comment: if i launch my app to the app store..then ios 10 users can use my apps or not??

Comment: I really happy to help :)